# Python - design a slider to control the input of a function

Tags: python, matplotlib, slider, ipywidgets

I have the following codes

```
def update(val):
    if val == 0:
        value = s.val
        ax1.cla()
        ax1.plot_surface(x, y, rm, cmap = cm.coolwarm, linewidth = 0, antialiased = False)        
    elif val == 1:
        value = s.val
        ax1.cla()
        ax1.plot_surface(x, y, rm1, cmap = cm.coolwarm, linewidth = 0, antialiased = False)
    elif val == 2:
        value = s.val
        ax1.cla()
        ax1.plot_surface(x, y, rm2, cmap = cm.coolwarm, linewidth = 0, antialiased = False)      
    
ax1.set_zlim(-110, -80)



slider = wg.IntSlider(value=1, min=1, max=3, description='this is     slider')
slideroutput = wg.Output()
display(slider, slideroutput)

def on_value_change(change):
    with slideroutput:
        print(change['new'])

slider.observe(on_value_change, names='value')


update(slideroutput)
plt.show()
```

If the input of update is "i", it shows the i-th 3D graph in the definition of update function, where i = 1, 2, 3.

How to design a slider such that when I move the control button of the slider, the output of the slider is 1, 2 or 3, which will become the input of  "update"?

For example

```
update(slider_button)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the function that you are looking for:

```
import ipywidgets as wg

slider = wg.IntSlider(value=1, min=1, max=3, description='this is slider')
slideroutput = wg.Output()
display(slider, slideroutput)

def on_value_change(change):
    with slideroutput:
        print(change['new'])

slider.observe(on_value_change, names='value')
```

However, I strongly advice you to find another alternative (for example: dropdown list or button instead of slider). Slider use `.observe`. This causes the program to be very heavy, especially when used in correlation with 3D plot. The above code has simply print command, however, you can see that it doesn't run that smooth. You can imagine how much worse it is if linked with 3D plot.

---edit---

```
numberonslider = []
def on_value_change(change):
    
    with slideroutput:
        numberonslider.append(change['new'])
        print(numberonslider[-1])
slider.observe(on_value_change, names='value')
```

Comment: Looks nice. However, is there a way to get the last value of slideroutput?  When I use "slideroutput[-1]", python says "'Output' object is not subscriptable". Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean with _last value_?

Comment: For example I move the slider and the slideroutput gives "2 3 2 3 1 2 1", the last value should be 1. However, I cannot use slideroutput[-1] to get this value. Is there any way to get the last value of the slideroutput?    Thanks!

Comment: When will this output be called? I mean, after which user action? The way to do it or whether it's possible depends strongly on it.

Comment: "slideroutput" is the output of the slider. I want this output to be the input of the function "update()" since this input will be the parameter of if-else loop in the function update().

Comment: Yes, and my question is: how will the function ``update()`` be called? using a ``Button``? Because without button, I see no benefits and use of doing this. But well, who am I to judge, see my answer below --edit--

Comment: You can check out the `continuous_update=True` keyword to only run your observed function when you let go of the slider, rather than on every value change as you slide.

Comment: @ac24 it could be that my machine is just running very slow, but by default even without typing ``continuous_update=True``, I somehow only get the value when I let go of the slider.